# jQuery UI Accordian: How to keep a particular window open by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

By default the first accordion window stays open, how can I specify a different one to be open by default instead of the first?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default

```
$('.accordian').accordion({
   collapsible: true        
});
```

Comment: The link that you have posted in it's `options` tab answers your question.

Comment: Are you serious you could not have clicked on the options tab on the page you linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `active = 2`

Try:

```
$(".accordian").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: 2
});
```

Or:

```
$(".accordian").activate(index); //for example replace index with 2
```